# Fetching of mails in third party iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to fetch all my gmail account mails in my iphone app. Is there any third party API which provides me some help on this. I am trying to use pop3 but not found success. Mail sending from third party app without using iphone default library is succeed using SMTP. Can we do such kind of thing for fetching mails also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [this](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am trying this and get back to you with status.